# Understanding Kubernetes eviction algorithm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

In have a situation where the node has `4GB memory` and actual memory usage looks as below:

| Pod | Memory Requested | Memory Limit | Memory Used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 GiB | 3.0 GiB | 1.0 GiB |
| 2 | 2.0 GiB | 3.0 GiB | 1.0 GiB |
| Free | 0.0 GiB | 0.0 GiB | 2.0 GB |

Since there is free memory, nothing gets evicted.

But now let's say both pods 1 and 2 start doing real work, and the situation changes to

| Pod | Memory Requested | Memory Limit | Memory Used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 GiB | 3.0 GiB | 3.0 GiB |
| 2 | 2.0 GiB | 3.0 GiB | 2.0 GiB |

and the Kubernetes eviction algorithm gets triggered.

In such a situation which pod will be evicted? Will it be `pod1` or `pod2?`.

I have already checked [pod selection rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#pod-selection-for-kubelet-eviction), but still not able to get an understanding of how eviction will work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, pod 1 will get evicted.  The Pod that is not using more memory than it requested will not get evicted.

This is mentioned in the Kubernetes documentation you link to:

> The kubelet uses the following parameters to determine the pod eviction order:
>
> 1. Whether the pod's resource usage exceeds requests
> 2. Pod Priority
> 3. The pod's resource usage relative to requests

In your example, pod 2's resource usage does not exceed requests (memory requested=2 GiB, actual use=2 GiB) so it is removed from the algorithm.  That leaves pod 1 as the only pod remaining, and it gets evicted.

Say pod 2 is also above its request.  Then for both pods, subtract actual utilization from the request, and the pod that's the most over its limit gets evicted.

Let's look at a little more complex example on a hypothetical 8 GiB node:

| Pod | Requested | Actual | Excess use |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4.0 GiB | 4.0 GiB | 0.0 GiB |
| 2 | 1.0 GiB | 2.0 GiB | **1.0 GiB** |
| 3 | 1.0 GiB | 1.3 GiB | 0.3 GiB |
| 4 | 0.0 GiB | 0.8 GiB | 0.8 GiB |

Pod 1 is using the most memory, but it is within its requests, so it is safe.  Subtracting actual use from requests, pod 2 is using the most excess memory and it is the one that will get evicted.  Pod 4 hasn't declared resource requests at all, and while it's safe in this scenario, it's at risk in general; absent pod 2, it's the pod using the most memory above its requests, even though it's the second-least absolute memory.